# Frequency of search term using solr

Tags: solr

I have a secondary index which stores the search terms executed on a primary index for searching documents. I want to run a search on the secondary index and list down the search terms in descending order of frequency of execution like I want to find the top 10 most searched terms.

The secondary index stores data in this format

```
Search Term | Date ...<some more irrelevant fields>
term1 | 01-01-2018
term2 | 01-01-2018
term3 | 02-01-2018
term1 | 02-01-2018
term3 | 03-01-2018
```

I need something like this which I can use java to manipulate. So any json with the search term and frequency from solr is okay.

```
Searh Term, Frequency
term1, 2
term2, 1
term3, 2
```

I have looked up some articles which state the use of Term Vector Component but those articles run search on the number of times a specific term exists in a document.

Can someone help me to get the desired result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html) to tally how often a given token appears in a field.

```
&facet=true&facet.field=term&facet.sort=count
```

There are also many other parameters you can give, such as to order by term or count.

Comment: This is working but I found a little problem.

It is taking each word of the search terms for faceting, but I want the entire term for faceting.
For example if I had a search term like "machine language", the current faceting is taking 'machine' and 'language' separately.
I want the entire term 'machine language' to be used for faceting.

Any idea how can I achieve this.

Comment: Yes, that will depend on the analysis of the field. Use a string field or a field with a KeywordTokenizer and a LowercaseFilter (to count terms without considering case). If you want to search the field for `machine` and get `machine language` as well, have one field for searching and one for faceting.